# How to make fallback for Google Font?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, fallback

How to make fallback for Google Font? If Google Font not available, then load from local server url, all the same font.
It's not typical css font fallback, because need all the same font.

Maybe, already exist decision for Webpack?

Answer (score 1):

Load local font using custom web-font API(@font-face) and also load google font.

```
p{font-family: google font , local web-font, system font;}

p{font-family: "Roboto","Times New Roman", serif;}
```

It will first try to load google web font. If not found it will go for local web font then if not found then it will fallback to system font.